# IBM Bluemix disconnecting the MqttAndroidClient after sometime

Tags: android, ibm-cloud, mqtt, iot

I am working on CC2650 sensortag and Bluemix(using IOT starter boilerplate) as a cloud solution.
The cc2650 android app uses MqttAndroidClient to connect to MQTT server provided by bluemix. The problem I am facing after sometime (around 7 mins) it get timedout.

Following exception is visible on the android studio console
*d:2f7tpk:ti-sensortag2:B0B448C07886: Timed out as no activity, keepAlive=240,000 lastOutboundActivity=1,463,309,545,312 lastInboundActivity=1,463,309,275,609 time=1,463,309,785,352 lastPing=1,463,309,545,312*

Please note that every 10 seconds I am publishing the data to server from my android client app. So not sure why it is saying no activity.
Keepalive interval is set to 120 seconds.

I confirmed it. It is IBM Bluemix which is disconnecting the client after approx 7 min. During this period client was continuously sending the data in 10 sec interval and that was also visible on the Bluemix device page.

Any idea why Bluemix is disconnecting it after 6-7 minutes (It is not fixed but out of 6 in 5 it got disconnected in 7 min and once it was around 6 min).

New observation:
The other observation is once it is disconnected then it takes 10-12 retries before I am able to reconnect to Bluemix server. From Mqttv3 client I get the exception "Unable to connect to server". But during this period I am able to ping to server through cmdline ping utility.

Answer (score 1):

It was because phone cpu was going in sleep mode.
http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=1599 explains in detail what all should be taken care in Android MQTT client.